# Can't navigate to other component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i've got 2 components. 
They are each on their own path.

I have a `<Link>` component in the first component, and when i click that, the second component is supposed to be rendered. 
The url after the #, changes fine, but nothing happens in the ui.

This is the main component:

```
export default class IntegrationApp extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Route path="/details/:encryptedId/:integrationType/" component={DetailsOverview} />
                <Route exact path="/:integrationSource?/" component={IntegrationsOverview} />
            </>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <IntegrationApp />
    </HashRouter>
    , document.getElementById('integrationsOverviewContainer'));
```

The `<Link>` is a custom component.

It looks like this:

```
export default class LinkForRouting extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        let cssClass = this.props.isButton ? ' btn ' : '';
        cssClass += this.props.isPrimary ? ' btn-primary ' : '';
        cssClass += this.props.customCssClass ? this.props.customCssClass : '';

        const clickEvent = this.props.handleClick ? () => this.props.handleClick() : ()=> function () { return null };

        return (
            <Link to={this.props.path} replace={true} className={cssClass} onClick={clickEvent}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Link>
        );
    }
}
```

The `<Link>` component is used inside the `<IntegrationsOverview>` component, like this:

```
 <LinkForRouting path={`/details/${integration.encryptedId}/${integration.integrationType}`} isButton={false} isPrimary={false} > Vis </LinkForRouting>
```

If i click the link, and then hit `F5` afterwards, then the `<DetailsOverview>` component renders fine, but if i just click the link, then the URL just changes, and nothing happens. 
Any idea of how to trigger the `<DetailsOverview>` component, to trigger when i click on the `<Link>` component?

Comment: On a side note, according to react docs reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html, "Note that many tools don’t support it yet so you might want to explicitly write <React.Fragment> until the tooling catches up."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved! 
My react solution, was part of a much larger, and older solution. 
This solution also had some references to angular, solution wide. 
I made those references, specific to the views that need them, and then routing in react started working!

Lesson learned, check included javascript.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the code posted above all of your components are extending PureComponent.

As React docs says:

> React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() only shallowly compares the objects. If these contain complex data structures, it may produce false-negatives for deeper differences. ***Only extend PureComponent when you expect to have simple props and state***, or use forceUpdate() when you know deep data structures have changed. Or, consider using immutable objects to facilitate fast comparisons of nested data.Furthermore, React.PureComponent’s shouldComponentUpdate() skips prop updates for the whole component subtree. Make sure all the children components are also “pure”.

In your case:

```js
export default class IntegrationApp extends React.PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <Route path="/details/:encryptedId/:integrationType/" component={DetailsOverview} />
                <Route exact path="/:integrationSource?/" component={IntegrationsOverview} />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

The IntegrationApp Component it is not expecting simple props and state also you should use a Switch instead of Fragment to wrap your Routes, then it becomes:

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  Switch,
  Route
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class IntegrationApp extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ( <
      Switch >
      <
      Route path = "/details/:encryptedId/:integrationType/"
      component = {
        DetailsOverview
      }
      /> <
      Route exact path = "/:integrationSource?/"
      component = {
        IntegrationsOverview
      }
      /> <
      /Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

I wrote a simple example on: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vk79jlrn4

Hope it can help you.

Comment: I've updated my solution with your suggested changes, but it didn't help. 
I then tried to use the code example you provided, inside my own solution, and that wouldn't work there either.
So it must be either something in my solution, or in my build step, that messes it up, i think.